# AS3 changing partial text color

Tags: actionscript-3, text, dynamic, colors

I've got a string in AS3 composed of two elements that is dynamically assigned to a `textField.`

**I want to make one element one color and the other a different color.**

Code below:

```
allInfoForSchedules = data[j].weekDay + " " + data[j].scheduleType + ".";
```

I can make the entire string change color but not just one part of it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices.

1. Convert the textfield to a html enabled textfield and format the text with html.
2. Convert the textfield into 2 textfield with the texts separated and change color of them separately

Comment: Thanks Ancide I used the first option!